# I keep getting unresponsive script error in firefox for jQuery script

Tags: firefox, script, jquery

Yesterday I started getting unresponsive script errors like 6 times a day.
And I know it has something to do with jQuery because I always get this in the error report:

```
Script: resource://gre/modules/commonj…nsion/data/jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
```

This happens when the script is running very long...

I've tried googling it and found many other people have a problem with this too and only solution mentioned was to change max_script_run_time which at least made the lag shorter, but it's not a solution..

I'm not sure if this is jQuery bug or Firefox bug, but does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting relates to Firefox add-ons.

Either you have installed or updated an add-on that is not working correctly or possibly you have a corrupted file.

Two things to try.

Firstly try restarting Firefox without add-ons, you can do this from the menu (<kbd>F10</kbd>). If that fixes the issue, you may need to track down the problem add-on.

However, you might find it easier to do the second options which is to refresh the install. If you press <kbd>F10</kbd> to get the menu, then choose Help/Troubleshooting Information, there are a couple of buttons on the top-right. Choose "Refresh Firefox". This will reset everything and you will need to reinstall add-ons. You should also backup your bookmarks as I can't remember whether that gets reset.

Comment: Bookmarks aren't deleted when you do a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you and followed the advice of Julian Knight. Turns out the Skype Add-on for Firefox was the culprit and my browser was instantly more responsive and faster after that. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  If you wish to post comments towards other people's answers you should earn enough reputation in order to do so.

Comment: It's still a possible an answer to the author's question. Seems like a common cause for the issue, too. Solution worked for me.

Comment: You should also let the author of the addon know that it had a problem so that it can be improved.